# Filling in missing row by last observation carried forward

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set as below with data of some rows missing:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to fill in the missing data by last observation carried forward as so:

[image]

I tried

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: `df = df.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: Or `df = df.ffill()`